# Effective torus action on a symplectic manifold

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions, symplectic-geometry

Consider a Hamiltonial $\mathbb T ^m$-action on a compact connected symplectic manifold $M$. Let $\mu : M \to \mathbb R ^m$ be the momentum map, $\mu= (\mu_1, \dots, \mu_m)$.

Assuming that the action is effective (ie, all elements except the identity move at least one point in $M$), I want to show that there is a point $p \in M$ such that $$\text{d}_p \mu_1, \dots, \text{d}_p \mu_m$$ are linearly independent.

**Remark.** I wanted to proof a Corollary of the well-known Atiyah-Guillemin-Sternberg theorem, that states that in the conditions of the questions (ie, of the theorem), the torus action has $m+1$ fixed points. But the linearly independence condition is the one that I miss.

Comment: I am sorry that your question is closed. I don't see the reason for the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to work in a coordinate-free fashion, as I consider this ultimately less confusing, so let $\mathfrak{t}$ denote the Lie algebra of $G:= \mathbb{T}^m$ and $\mathfrak{t}^*$ its dual.

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a compact symplectic manifold and let $\mu : M \to \mathfrak{t}^*$ be 'the' moment map associated to a Hamiltonian $G$-action on $(M, \omega)$. You are seeking for the existence of a point $p \in M$ such that the differential $d\mu_p : T_pM \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective.

The effectiveness of this Hamiltonian toric action not only implies the existence of such a point $p \in M$, but also that the set of such points is an open dense subset of $M$.

That this set is open follows readily from the fact that the condition "$d\mu_p : T_pM \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is surjective" on $p$ is open. This part does not require faithfulness of the action.

Let us now rephrase the surjectivity condition you are interested in. For $p \in M$, let $X_p : \mathfrak{t} \to T_pM : \xi \mapsto X_p(\xi) := (X_{\xi})(p)$ where $X_{\xi}$ is the Hamiltonian vector field associated to the Hamiltonian function $H_{\xi}(p) := \langle \mu(p), \xi \rangle$. From $X_p(\xi) \lrcorner \, \omega_p = - (dH_{\xi})_p = - \langle d\mu_p, \xi \rangle$ and the nondegeneracy of $\omega$, it follows that $\mathrm{ker} \, X_p \subset \mathfrak{t}$ is the annihilator of the set $\mathrm{im} \, d\mu_p \subset \mathfrak{t}^*$. Consequently, $d\mu_p$ is surjective is and only if $X_p$ is injective, that is if and only if the stabilizer subgroup $G_p \le G$ is discrete (which is to say that its Lie algebra is just $\{0\} \subset \mathfrak{t}$).

Therefore you are interested in the set of points $p \in M$ whose stabilizer is zero-dimensional, that is the complement of those points $q \in M$ whose stabilizer is at least one-dimensional. As every connected component of a Lie group has the same dimension, we can only consider below connected subgroups of dimension at least one. Notice also that a stabilizer subgroup is closed.

Let $K < G$ be a connected closed subgroup of dimension at least 1. It is thus comppact, but it is also Lie. From these properties, there is a nonzero $\xi \in Lie(K)$ generating a one-parameter subgroup of $K$ which is dense in $K$. (Indeed, as $K$ is a compact abelian Lie group, it is a torus, so it is a product of a number of circles of some periods and it suffices to choose $\xi$ with components which are incommensurable with those periods.) But $\xi$ acts on $M$ through the Hamiltonian $H_{\xi}$. It follows that the points $q \in M$ fixed by $K$ are the same as the critical points of $H_{\xi}$, a crucial observation.

Another crucial observation of Atiyah and of Guillemin-Sternberg is that for a Hamiltonian torus action, each Hamiltonian $H_{\xi}$ is either constant or a Morse-Bott function on $M$. In the latter case, the set of regular points of $H_{\xi}$ is an open dense subset of $M$.

If one assumes that the action is effective, then $H_{\xi}$ is not constant for $\xi \neq 0$. Combining this with the two previous paragraphs, we conclude that for any closed subgroup $K < G$ of dimension at least 1, the set of points in $M$ which do not have $K$ in their stabilizer is an open dense set of $M$.

To conclude the argument, we need one last ingredient, which is to show that the collection of subgroups $K < G$ of dimension at least 1 appearing as stabilizers of the action is countable. Indeed, it would follow that the set of points $p \in M$ whose stabilizer is discrete is the intersection of *countably* many open dense sets, and would thus be itself dense according to the Baire category theorem.

To show that this collection is countable, there is two instructive ways:

1) Recall that stabilizers are compact Lie subgroups and have as such finitely many connected components. The number of closed connected subgroups $K < G$ is countable; this follows from arguing on the possible closure of one-parameter subgroups of $G$. Thus stabilizers subgroups belong to a countable family.

2) A result related to what Guillemin-Sternberg call the Koszul-Mostow theorem in their book *Symplectic techniques in physics* states that for a smooth group action by a compact Lie group on a compact manifold, the number of conjugacy classes of stabilizer subgroups is finite. When the group is abelian, it follows that the number of stabilizers is finite.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I guess another related argument for this is that the principal orbit type is just the {1} for effective toric actions.

Comment: I was wondering if the opposite is true, assume that  is a submersion in open dense (or maybe the whole manifold) then is it true that the action is effective ?

I've seen in a few places the definition of effective moment map to be $\mu $ is submersion, I was wondering if moment map being effective is same as action being effective.

Comment: @Soham Not quite true. Consider an effective Hamiltonian action of $\mathbb{T}^m$ on $(M, \omega)$. Any Lie homomorphism $h : \mathbb{T}^m \to \mathbb{T}^m$ which is a local diffeomorphism induces a Hamiltonian action on $M$ which has a moment map which is related to the initial moment map by an invertible linear map of $(\mathfrak{t^m})^*$ (hence preserving the submersive character of the moment map), but the induced action is not effective if $h$ isn't injective. Example : Rotations on $S^2$ along the equator, and rotations twice as fast.